# Schema.prototype.pre is not a function

Tags: node.js, authentication, mongoose, backend, schema

The `.pre` function of Mongoose model is not found.

```js
// usersModel.js

const UserSchema = model(
  //name of table in db
  "UserSchema",
  new Schema({
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Email is required"],
      unique: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Password is required"],
      minlength: 8,
    },

  })
);

User.pre("save", function () { console.log("Hello from pre save")});
//or
User.pre("save", () => console.log("Hello from pre save"));

module.exports = UserSchema;
```

```json
// package.json

"dependencies": {
  "cors": "^2.8.5",
  "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
  "express": "^4.18.2",
  "mongoose": "^6.8.0"
},
"engines": {
  "node": "14.x"
}
```

I am trying use `model.pre('save', function(){})` to hash the user password, but I am getting this error:

```
UserSchema.pre("save", () => console.log("Hello from pre save"));
           ^
TypeError: UserSchema.pre is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\TravelC\backend\models\usersModel.js:44:12)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose it's just a typo when you write

```
User.pre("save", function () { console.log("Hello from pre save")});
```

It should be

```
UserSchema.pre("save", function () { console.log("Hello from pre save")});
```

in your actual code.

The UserSchema that you declared is [Models](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html) while Mongoose supports you to use [pre](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#pre) middleware with [Schemas](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#schemas) instead.
The logic should be defined as:

```
const userSchema = new Schema(...);
userSchema.pre('save', function() {...}) // does not use arrow function here
const UserModel = model('UserShema', userSchema);
```

Comment: This helped, thank you!
I will keep in mind that "Mongoose supports to use pre middleware with Schemas"

Answer (score 1):

```
User.pre("save", function () { console.log("Hello from pre save")});
//or
User.pre("save", () => console.log("Hello from pre save"));
```

**change to**

```
userSchema.pre("save", function () { console.log("Hello from pre save")});
//or
userSchema.pre("save", () => console.log("Hello from pre save"));
```